# NSSortDescriptor and [__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: swift, swift2, nsmanagedobject, nssortdescriptor

I am using sort descriptor to sort an array of an NSManagedObject (CoreData).

I have two sort descriptors for Int16 value (added the second one today).

For some reason, when trying to sort my array with the added descriptor, it crashes with:

```
[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber localizedStandardCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I even tried to change my data model (add an attribute as Int16 and populate it) but the app crashes every time I try to use the newly added descriptor.

The descriptor is very simple:
let sortDescriptor4 = NSSortDescriptor(key: "the_int16_property", ascending: false, selector: "localizedStandardCompare:")

I am at a loss. Any advice would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`localizedStandardCompare:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/localizedStandardCompare:) is a method of `NSString` to
"compare strings as sorted by the Finder".

Key-Value Coding for *numerical* Core Data properties (like "Int 16") uses `NSNumber` instances, and that class does not respond to
`localizedStandardCompare:`.

Just use the default `compare:` selector:

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "the_int16_property", ascending: false, selector: "compare:")
// Swift 2.2 or later:
NSSortDescriptor(key: "the_int16_property", ascending: false, selector: #selector(NSNumber.compare(_:)))
```

or simply

```
NSSortDescriptor(key: "the_int16_property", ascending: false)
```

Comment: Thanks! It was actually a copy n' paste error. Did not even noticed it!